# how to verify website in google+ page?

Tags: seo, google-plus, google-search-console

I have created a google+ page for my website.

I want to verify my website link.As per the instructions, I have downloaded the verification file, uploaded it to the domain & trying to verify the link.

But when I do that, I get an error

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title> Title of the Website </title>
</head>
<frameset border="0" rows="100%,*" cols="100%" frameborder="no">
<frame name="TopFrame" scrolling="yes" noresize src="http://abc.co.in/google366be22c1c1da379.html">
<frame name="BottomFrame" scrolling="no" noresize><noframes></noframes>  </frameset>
</html>
```

I have the Website link as which I am trying to verify is:-

**http://www.maindomain.in**

Which is redirected to another domain to

**http://www.abc.co.in**

If it the usual hosting, then such error would have not come but in the current scenario how do I verify the website link.

Comment: Sounds like you're using some sort of domain masking. Give us the actual URLs to confirm instead of fake made-up ones.